# Play! Framework Route Wildcard for root address

Tags: java, backbone.js, playframework, routes, wildcard

I'm using Backbone for a SPA, and I'm using its router as well. I need to set a wildcard in the routes file of my application for the back-end, but I can't figure out how to set it for the ROOT URL. I've tried `GET /*path controllers.Application.cms(path)` but it doesn't work if I navigate to `localhost:9000`. Also, `GET *path controllers.Application.cms(path)` with the slash omitted is not a valid route. Is there any way I can set a wildcard to catch all uncaught routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define an additional route before `/*path` in the config/routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.cms(path="")
GET     /*path                      controllers.Application.cms(path)
```

Comment: You would think that a competent programmer could think of a solution as easy as that, god I feel stupid :P Thanks